# Parsing and joining data in a CSV files using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, performance, csv, time-series, large-data

I am trying to parse and join data in one very large csv file with python and wanted to see how to do it efficiently. The picture below shows an example of how the data is stored in the csv file. The actual data has 50 data columns with corresponding timestamps and more than 100,000 rows of data. I would like to combine all the data with one timestamp with the average for each minute. Data is collected every 20 secs so there are three timestamps per minute.

[Example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45DkV.jpg)

enter code here

```
import pandas as pd

import os

import csv

daylightsavings = [pd.Timestamp(2017,03,12,03), pd.Timestamp(2017,11,05,03)]

dir1 = r'C:\XXX'

def f_daylightsavings(x):

    if x<daylightsavings[0] or x>=daylightsavings[1]:
        return x
    else:
        x = x - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
        return x

def to_df(dat):

    df = pd.read_csv(dat, sep=';', header=0, na_values='NAN', encoding= 'UTF-16', memory_map=True)

    if len(df.columns)<2:
        df = pd.read_csv(dat, sep=',', header=0, na_values='NAN', encoding= 'UTF-16', memory_map=True)

    pieces = [df.iloc[:,2*i:2*i+2].dropna().drop_duplicates() for i in range(len(df.columns)/2)]

    for i in range(len(pieces)):
        print 'parsing ' + str(i) + '/' + str(len(pieces))

        pieces[i].iloc[:,0]=pd.to_datetime(pieces[i].iloc[:,0], 
        infer_datetime_format=True).apply(f_daylightsavings)
        pieces[i].set_index(pieces[i].columns[0], inplace=True)      
        pieces[i] = pieces[i].resample('1T').mean()

    for i in range(len(pieces)-1):
        print 'joining ' + str(i) + '/' + str(len(pieces)-1)
        pieces[0] = pieces[0].join(pieces[i+1], how='outer') 

    return pieces[0]
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?  Even if you just hack something up you could then run it through Python profile and maybe what you've got it fast enough :)

Comment: Edited my post to add the code that we developed so far that works but it takes a long time to process through the data. Wanted to see if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: That is helpful.  While you wait for a good answer, give python -m cProfile  a spin, you may see one part that is slow and look to simply optimize that step.